# Can applications purchased through the App Store be used after deauthorization?

Tags: mac-appstore

If I deauthorize a computer from the account used to purchase a certain app, will that app continue to work as usual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mac App Store does not currently have the concept of an "authorized" or "deauthorized" computer. If you download an app legitimately from the Mac App Store, it is DRM free (at least with regard to execution), and completely functional on your computer.

The immediate answer to your question is actually that you cannot deauthorize your computer in the Mac App Store :).

Comment: The Terms and Conditions http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html#APPS state that you can download apps onto up to 5 "iTunes-authorized computers" does this mean that once you hit that limit you can *never* install the app on a subsequent computer using the Mac App Store? That seems a little unlikely.

Comment: So perhaps I should reword it to "while the legal documents note 5, there is no technical solution in place for de-authorizing a computer". Because all you have to do in the Mac App Store is log in.

Comment: @Rich: I don't think that applies, since it later says 'The above terms (i) to (iv) do not apply to App Store Products', and (i) and (iv) are the ones that mention the 5-computer limit; then even later it says 'If you are an individual acting in your personal capacity, you may download and use an application from the Mac App Store (“Mac App Store Product”) for personal, non-commercial use on any Apple-branded products running Mac OS X (“Mac Computer”) that you own or control.' which seems to imply no limit...

Comment: @Gordon I think the "App Store" in the first part you quoted is referring specifically to the *iOS* App Store. (The document is meticulous about distinguishing between the "App Store and the "Mac App Store".) Hopefully you're right about the implication in the second quote, though.